# TypeError: Cannot destructure property `stat` of 'undefined' or 'null'

Tags: javascript, android, ios, macos, react-native

I am getting a TypeError when running npm install -g react-native project on mac.

full error

TypeError: Cannot destructure property `stat` of 'undefined' or 'null'.
at Object. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/node-gyp/lib/index.js:2:29)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to initialize React Native project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51196802/how-to-initialize-react-native-project)

Comment: it doesn't work, It even not allow me to run npm install

Comment: it would seem that your problem is not with react native then. Rewrite your question to include the error messages associated with running node and npm - not react native.

Comment: It works after deleting and re install node.js manually, previously I used this cmd 'brew install node' for installing node.

Comment: I installed macOS Big Sur, and I have this issue now (on projects that used to work fine before that update). Maybe it's related, I'm still investigating.

Comment: Try download and re install node

Answer (score 2):

Might be you are using  `npm@latest`. Looks to me some issue with lates NPM, I have changed my version with `RUN npm install npm@6.14.11 -g` in my docker file working for me.

Answer (score 2):

When I upgraded to Big Sur, I had the same issue. It's something to do with npm, not react-native.

Here's what I did to solve the problem:

Delete everything related to nodejs:

```
sudo rm -rf ~/.npm ~/.nvm ~/node_modules ~/.node-gyp ~/.npmrc ~/.node_repl_history
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/npm /usr/local/bin/node-debug /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/node-gyp
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/share/man/man1/node* /usr/local/share/man/man1/npm*
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/include/node /usr/local/include/node_modules
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules /usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d
sudo rm -rf /opt/local/include/node /opt/local/bin/node /opt/local/lib/node
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/share/doc/node
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/share/systemtap/tapset/node.stp

brew uninstall node
brew doctor
brew cleanup --prune-prefix
```

And then install nvm again via:

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.37.2/install.sh | bash
```

Now, I was able to install all of my dependencies since now I've got a fresh copy of npm(for me it was 6.4.1).

Answer (score 1):

As usual, Mac OS updates tend to break stuff.

In case you're using NVM too (like me).
I faced this issue too and found that NVM is using a node version called 'system'. I never seen it before and NVM should be using the version I set it to use.

So I decided to update NVM. (See: https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/blob/master/README.md#installing-and-updating)

Seems to work after that.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using `npm install -g react-native`.

Please read through the React Native docs on how to do your environment setup: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup

Answer (score 0):

In case that you have the same error when running any command that has `npm`, you might have wrong npm version with node 8.

Running this will reverse your npm to node 6.

`curl -qs https://www.npmjs.com/install.sh|npm_install=6.14.11 sh`

Reference:
https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/2599